# get matplotlib lines from pandas plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

pandas df.plot returns 
axes : matplotlib.AxesSubplot or np.array of them

I need to get the lines object, as returned from matplotlib.plot:
Return value is a list of lines that were added.

Obviously, I can just use mpl directly instead of pandas.plot, but is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The pandas plotting function indeed returns the axes object.

```
ax = df.plot()  # returns matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot
```

If the plot creates a single line, you can easily get that with

```
line = ax.lines[0]
```

If it creates several lines, you would need to know the order by which they are created to index the axes'  lines

```
line4 = ax.lines[3]
```